# SVN web browser client with log search capability?

Tags: svn, webclient

We want integrate odd HP Service Desk with SVN via SVN web browser client.

HP Service Desk generate link to SVN web browser client like this
`http://websvn/commits?text=SD#321` , where 321 - Service Desk issue number

That must produce list of commits which log message contain text "SD#321".
Which SVN web browser client have this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found websvn on http://www.websvn.info

URL's like

http://demo.websvn.info/log.php?repname=WebSVN&path=%2F&isdir=1&sr=1269&er=1&max=40&search=321

with  *search=321*  in url path satisfy me

Answer (score 1):

[Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) has something similar - it reads new log messages, parses them for ticket numbers (eg fixed #3) which is then linked to the relevant ticket.

If you look at the ticket itself, it will have a list of changesets that have that message. eg. [Ticket 8569](http://www.redmine.org/issues/8569) in Redmine itself shows 'associated revisions' at the bottom right. Click the revision, you see the files in the changeset, click them you can get a diff. etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [full-text search](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/search/) feature of VisualSVN Server. Here is an example:

https://demo-server.visualsvn.com/!/#asf/search?q=%22JCR-4859%22&type=history

The example shows all commits that mention ticket JCR-4859 in log message.